# Method not allowed rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am making an ajax post call to a controller. My Ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'/chefUI/configure/save_roles',
  data:{ app_name: appname, role_list: role_list},...});
```

My Routes file is:

```
scope "/chefUI" do
    post '/configure/save_roles', to: 'admin#update_app_roles'
end
```

And my controller has:

```
def update_app_roles
    begin
      application_name = params["app_name"]
      puts application_name
      role_name_list = params["role_list"]
      puts role_name_list
      if application_name and !role_name_list.empty?
      ...
```

And I am getting a 405 Method Not Allowed response. I'm not sure what are the reasons this might happen. Could someone help me figure out what I'm missing here? I don't why my post request is not even reaching my controller.

---

### **Update:**

Log file

```
Started GET "/chefUI/configure/app_roles?app_name=MFRH" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-24 15:08:51 +0530 Processing by AdminController#app_roles as */*   Parameters: {"app_name"=>"MFRH"}   [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["username", "an9v0s7"]]   [1m[36mApplication Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "applications".* FROM "applications" WHERE (lower(app_name) = 'mfrh')  ORDER BY "applications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m   [1m[35mRole Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "application_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "application_roles"."role_id" WHERE "application_roles"."application_id" = $1  ORDER BY roles.name ASC  [["application_id", 1]] Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)


Started POST "/chefUI/configure/save_roles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-24 15:08:57 +0530
```

### **Another Update:**

I just found out that I'm getting that response for all my post requests. They were all working before, I created a bunch on new models and suddenly none of them are working.

Comment: if you remove `begin ... rescue` block from a controller action, what kind of error you see in the rails log file?

Comment: I don't see any error, I just see the post request, then its empty There is no console output from the puts I've given in the controller

Comment: **remove begin ... rescue block from a controller action**

Comment: Yeah I removed it and tried, I still see its empty, The request is not reaching the controller action

Comment: please show us rails log file with a relevant request

Comment: after line `Started POST .....` has something?

Comment: I just found out that I'm getting that response for all my post requests.

Comment: do you see a post route `/chefUI/configure/save_roles` in the  `rake routes` output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84160/discussion-between-anirudh-and-).

Comment: I removed the below line in application.rb and the issue got resolved.
config.assets.prefix="/chefUI"
I don't understand what assets.prefix has to do with POST requests.

Comment: post it as answer i want upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the below line in application.rb and the issue got resolved. `config.assets.prefix="/chefUI"`

I don't understand what config.assets.prefix has to do with POST requests, but this resolved my issue.

Would love to understand the reason though.

Comment: After about 2 days of debugging, I have finally figured out why this is the case!!

Answer (score 4):

This problem is a bit deeper than thought before.

Rails does not like when a route path and the asset directory are in the same subdirectory.

When making a post request, you will get `method not allowed`. The problem is there can be no overlap with paths and the asset directory. The problem is specifically with `POST` requests in that path. I am assuming somewhere in rails, they must have disabled all non-GET requests for the assets directory.

---

```
scope "/chefUI" do
    post '/configure/save_roles', to: 'admin#update_app_roles'
end

config.assets.prefix="/chefUI/assets"
                                ^ You need this part so they don't overlap.
```

---

In this very simple app below, you will get a `method not allowed` error. Because the path `/welcome` is being used for a route and for an asset prefix.

**File: `config/environment/development.rb`**

```
config.assets.prefix = '/welcome'
```

**File: `config/routes.rb`**

```
resources :welcomes, path: 'welcomes', only: ['index', 'create']
```

**File: `app/controllers/welcomes_controller.rb`**

```
class WelcomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @welcome = 'hello';
  end

  def create
    @welcome = 'world';
  end
end
```

**File: `app/views/welcomes/index.html.rb`**

```
<%= form_for(@welcome) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

**File: `app/views/welcomes/create.html.rb`**

```
<h1>Welcomes#create</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcomes/create.html.erb</p>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but due to a `POST` request done by code generated by `rails g scaffold`. It made no sense. It was a bright new app with just one model! All code generated by `rails g`.

But, in my case, I named my model as `asset` and the path was conflicting with the standard `assets/` path for static resources.

Turns out my solutions was to do the right opposite of @anirudh's solution: to include in my `config/application.rb` the follow:

```rb
config.assets.prefix="/my-app-assets"
```

Server restarted and then problem solved: I successfully created my asset record in DB!